# How to merge dupblicate data value in object array

Tags: javascript

How can I merge array in js

for example I've array like this

```
[{
    "team": team1,
    "groupname": "group1",
    "emp-data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1",
    }],
},
{
    "team": team1,
    "groupname": "group1",
    "emp-data": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2",
    }],
},
{
    "team": team2,
    "groupname": "group1",
    "emp-data": [{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "name3",
    }],
}],
```

I want output like this
-  I want to push emp-data into same team and same group-name

```
[{
    "team": team1,
    "groupname": "group1",
    "emp-data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1",
    },{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2",
    }],
},
{
    "team": team2,
    "groupname": "group1",
    "emp-data": [{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "name3",
    }],
}]
```

I've try to loop array and push it using if else to check but still not working

Comment: well, your wanted output is invalid atm. Do you want `emp-data` to be in an array?

Comment: Is it possible to have two objects with the same `team` but different `groupname`?

Comment: yes it posibble @Ace

Comment: @Ach is `emp-data` supposed to become an array?

Comment: oh yes my bad thanks I'll update my question and I'wll try to looking at reduce array

Comment: If two objects have the same `team` but different `groupname` they should not be merged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will merge  objects with the same `team` and `groupname`

```js
const teams = [{
    "team": "team1",
    "groupname": "group1",
    "emp-data": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
    },
  },
  {
    "team": "team1",
    "groupname": "group1",
    "emp-data": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2",
    },
  },
  {
    "team": "team2",
    "groupname": "group1",
    "emp-data": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "name3",
    },
  }
]

const merged_teams = {};
teams.forEach(team => {
  const merged_team = merged_teams[team.team + team.groupname];
  if (!merged_team) {
    merged_teams[team.team + team.groupname] = team;
    team["emp-data"] = [team["emp-data"]]
    return;
  }
  merged_team["emp-data"].push(team["emp-data"])
});

console.log(Object.values(merged_teams))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` to map each `team` and `groupname` to a key in a new object which holds you're accumulated object. Then you can use `Object.values` to get the accumulated objects:

```js
const arr = [{team:"team1",groupname:"group1","emp-data":{id:1,name:"name1"}},{team:"team1",groupname:"group1","emp-data":{id:2,name:"name2"}},{team:"team2",groupname:"group1","emp-data":{id:3,name:"name3"}}];

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {team, groupname, ...rest}) => {
  const key = `${team}-${groupname}`;
  const empData = rest["emp-data"];
  if (!(key in acc)) {
    acc[key] = {team, groupname, ...rest};
    acc[key]["emp-data"] = [];
  }
  acc[key]["emp-data"].push({ ...empData});
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```